# Swift - add text to dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

While I am trying to add a value to a dictionary, it always fail while I try to set the value from my textField.text. I have a text field, that I want to add to a dictionary, with this code:

```
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()

dict.updateValue(usernameText.text!, forKey: "key")

print(dict["key"]!)
```

However, on the print it doesn't show anything. When I am setting the value as "a value" - it prints fine. How come I can't add a text field value?

Comment: try "var dict: NSMutableDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()", add value as "dict["key"] = value as! String"

Comment: @IshmeetSingh Thanks for your reply, but I have unfortunately also tried this with no luck.

Comment: What does it print?

Answer (score 2):

What type is usernameText ? and are you certain that there is any text in it ?

try adding print(usernameText.text!) to make sure.

I tested with UITextField and could not reproduce the problem when there is text in the .text property.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
dict["key"] = usernameText.text!
```

*Update:*

Just tried this code:

```
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()        
dict.updateValue("Foo", forKey: "key")

print(dict["key"]!)
```

and it prints me as I expected `Foo`, try the following code, setting non optional value under `"key"` key:

```
if let aText = usernameText.text {
    dict.updateValue(aText, forKey: "key")
}
```

Comment: Try to change `var dict = [String:AnyObject]()` to `var dict = [String:String]()`, and also check what text you are trying to add.

Comment: That's the problem, I need the dictionary to be of type AnyObject, since I will be storing both booleans, ints and strings.

Comment: Please see the comments on the other answer.